# Why does Microsoft 365 Office Insider Beta Channel show Beta Channel but version remains Current Channel?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft

I subscribed to Microsoft 365 Family and joined Office Insider Beta Channel. The license section of Excel shows "You're signed up for Beta channel" but the About Excel section shows "Current Channel". I updated it a lot of times after subscribing for Beta, but it never actually download the beta channel builds.

[image]

Comment: You have the very current production version (just checked my own).  Did you run Office Updates manually to see if that moves you into the Beta channel.

Comment: I am manually updating for 3 days now with no luck.

Comment: Post in the Office Insider forum to see if they can help. I have Windows 11 Insider but production Office.

Comment: That is, after manual update, Excel still does not show up in the "account" registered Beta channel?

Comment: It shows "you're signed up for Beta channel" but never contains formulae like vstack().

Comment: Just to confirm, are you not on any "Microsoft 365 for Business, Enterprise, or University" plans? I realize you have indicated it's the "Microsoft 365 Family" plan, but those three plans are managed by an Administrator. So out of interest, I opted into the Office Insider Preview and was immediately notified the updates were being installed by the Click to Run installer.  When you opted into the preview builds, did that happen for you?  Do you have any diagnostic reporting disabled on your system? Needless to say, after it finished installation of the update, 15505.20000 was installed.

Comment: I wanted to point out that VSTACK requires [2203 (Build 15104)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c) the current version is [2206 (Build 15330.20246)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/current-channel#version-2206-july-12) which means the build you have installed already has the function you are looking to use.  Since that isn't your actual question, I won't be submitting an answer.  Honestly, it might just be easier to uninstall and reinstall Office 365.  **That is how it's supposed to work, at least.** I can't check now